# Low Power when Running Multiple Kitchen Appliances, No Breakers Tripped

Tags: electrical

We're having an issue in our home where, when running multiple appliances in our kitchen, each of them gets low power. For instance, when running both the oven, the stove, and the microwave, each will take a very long time to heat anything. When running individually, they work as they should. Everything in our house runs on electric.

We had an electrician out and mentioned this problem, but they didn't see anything unusual. I'm at a loss, as it seems to me like the breaker should trip if it's overloaded. Any suggestions for troubleshooting or tracing down this issue?

Comment: What country are you located in?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. More info (e.g. the line voltages with no and lots of load) would help us help you.

Comment: Yes, do you have a voltmeter?

Comment: You've got a big problem.  Possibly a lost pole, but also possibly a lost neutral. In the latter case, when the voltage sags in the kitchen, it is spiking somewhere else, which is very, very serious.  We had one of those last month, and the kitchen was where it was most apparent.  Neutral wire was broken clean off at the pole.